# Showing that the function $f(x,y)=x+y-ye^x$ is non-negative in the region $x+y≤1,x≥0,y≥0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

ok, since it's been so long when I took Calculus, I just wanna make sure I'm not doing anything wrong here.

Given $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x,y)=x+y-ye^x$. I would like to show that the function is nonnegative in the region $x+y\leq 1, \;\;x\geq 0, \;\;y\geq 0$.

Now my game plan is as follows:
1. Show the function is non-negative on the boundary of the region
2. Show the function takes a positive value in the interior of the region
3. Show that the function has no critical points in the interior of the region
4. By continuity the function is non-negative everywhere in the region.

Is the above sufficient or am I doing something wrong? Would there be a better way to show this?

Comment: Idea is sound. If it is negative somewhere in the interior, then it reaches a negative minimum. That's not on the boundary, so it is at a critical point.

Comment: How about Lagrange multiplier? You'll get a stationaty point and if the point is not in the range, then you'll just check the boundaries. The stationary point can be local minima, local maxima or saddle point. If the function is non-negative you should get just positive values.

Comment: @AndreNicolas, thanks. Just wanted to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try using Lagrange multiplier:

The function is:

$$f(x,y) = x + y - ye^x$$

and constraint are:

$$g(x,y) = x+y \leq 1$$
$$h(x) = x \geq 0$$
$$j(y) = y \geq 0$$

So using Lagrange multiplier now we have:

$$F(x,y,\lambda,\lambda_1,\lambda_2) = x + y - ye^x - \lambda(x+y-1) - \lambda_1(x) - \lambda_2(y)$$

Now we take parital derivatives:

$$F_x = 1 - ye^x - \lambda - \lambda_1 = 0$$
$$F_y = 1 - e^x - \lambda - \lambda_2 = 0$$
$$\lambda(x+y-1) = 0$$
$$\lambda_1(x) = 0$$
$$\lambda_2(y) = 0$$

Now we have 8 cases:

1) $\lambda = \lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 0$

This implies one solution $(x,y) = (0,1)$

2) $\lambda = \lambda_1 = y = 0$

Now in $F_x$ we have $1=0$, which is not posible, so this case doesn't give a solution.

3) $\lambda = x = \lambda_2 = 0$

Now in $F_x$ we have $y + \lambda_1 = 1$, because all $\lambda$ values are positive, we get $y \leq 1$. So the solutions are $(x,y) = (0,y)$, where $0 \leq y \leq 1$

4) $\lambda = x = y = 0$

Simply this implies one solution $(x,y) = (0,0)$

5) $x + y - 1 = \lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 0$

This implies a solution that we've already obtained $(x,y) = (0,1)$

6) $x + y - 1 = \lambda_1 = y = 0$

This simply implies one solution $(x,y) = (1,0)$

7) $x + y - 1 = x = \lambda_2  = 0$

This simply implies one solution $(x,y) = (0,1)$

8) $x + y - 1 = x = y = 0$

This case doesn't imply any solution because it's a contradiction.

Now we have 4 distinct solutions we check them all now:

1) $(x,y) = (0,1)$

$$f(x,y) = x + y - ye^x = 1 - 1 = 0$$

2) $(x,y) = (0,y)$

$$f(x,y) = x + y - ye^x = y - y = 0$$

3) $(x,y) = (0,0)$

$$f(x,y) = x + y - ye^x = 0$$

4) $(x,y) = (1,0)$

$$f(x,y) = x + y - ye^x = 1$$

This means that $f(x,y)$ has minimum of $0$ at point $(0,y)$ and maximum of $1$ at point $(1,0)$.

Q.E.D.